# Passing a list to a parameter of an API POST method in Powershell

Tags: api, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm having some difficulty passing a list of strings to an API method using Powershell.

What I've tried:
What haven't I tried? My latest incarnation is this:

```
$uri = "http://localhost:15207/v1/API/GetFoos"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
$contents = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

$contents.Add('Foo_1')
$contents.Add('Foo_1000002')

$body = @{
    "someParam"="string1"
    "contents"= $contents
}

Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Body $body -Method Post
```

This results in the following value being received by the API:

[0] = "Foo_1 Foo_1000002"

But I've tried arrays, and all sorts of different combinations of parenthesis, brackets, single quotes, and double quotes. In all cases, the contents parameter either receives an object type, or a single value that is the concatenated combination of the values I'm trying to pass across.

I'm sure I'm not the first person having to pass a list of strings to an API method, but searching for this includes a lot of common terms resulting in unrelated matches.

Comment: Are you opposed to using Invoke-WebRequest, specifying your own content type, and crafting the body yourself? I've been doing that with good results.

Comment: @Patrick87: I'm not opposed to any solution that will get this to work. I've been using Powershell for about a week and a half now, so any information is valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Invoke-RestMethod, take a look at Invoke-WebRequest instead. Maybe something like this would work:

```
$uri = "http://localhost:15207/v1/API/GetFoos"

$body = @{}
$body.someParam = 'string1'
$body.contents = ('Foo1', 'Foo_1000002')
$requestJson = $body | ConvertTo_Json

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Body $requestJson -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post

#Need to convert the JSON content into something we can use
$responseObject = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: Fantastic. I'm going to wait a bit to see if anyone else has other solutions, but this certainly works.

Comment: Having played with this a bit more yesterday, there's a few things that could improve this answer. I highly suggest restructuring the example to build out an object. IE: `$body = @{} $body.someParam = 'string1' $body.contents = ('Foo_1', 'Foo_1000002')`. And then use `$body | ConvertTo-Json`. This will automatically escape anything being sent across (in my actual problem, I'm sending double quotes and forward slashes across). In order to be able to do anything with the content of the response for `Invoke-WebRequest`, you'll need to use `ConvertFrom-Json` as well.

Comment: @Ellesedil I've made some edits to try to incorporate your comments. If the code above doesn't work, or isn't what you had in mind, perhaps you can fix it? At 600 rep I think you can suggest edits, please let me know if that's not the case. More generally, in the future, if you know a way to improve something, feel free to do it... once posted, this is community content after all.

Comment: It looks great and is pretty much exactly what I'm now doing for this problem. I touched up a few things, but this is solid.